# Select specific data from second table using output from first table

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have two table. One is `account` and the other is `client` table. The user will give input and in this case is `19`. What I want to do is that I want to select **ONLY** a single  `name` from `client` using `client_id` as identifier and only using a **single**  select statement. I could do select query twice but that's not what I wanted.

So to explain it better: User give input such as $id = `19`, I will use `id` from `account` table to identify `client_id` which in this case is `17`. I will then select `name` from `client` table using `client_id`.

`account` table
[image: account table]

`client` table
[image]

I already take a look at `join` and `left join` and I'm still stuck. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

My current not working code:

```
$sql = " SELECT account.id, client.client_id\n"
    . " FROM account, client\n"
    . " WHERE account.id = 19";
```

Comment: why newline characters in your query....that's not good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which column is used to join the two tables.

It's an unfortunate fact about the SQL language that the *default* behavior is to join two tables by matching each row in one table to every row in the other table.  That is, every possible pairing is part of the result set.  SQL doesn't have any way of inferring which column(s) you want to use as the join criteria, so you have to specify the condition yourself.

Here's a better form for the query:

```
$sql = " SELECT account.id, client.client_id
    FROM account JOIN client USING (client_id) 
    WHERE account.id = 19";
```

Do use the `JOIN` syntax.  It has been the standard way of doing joins in SQL since 1992.  The comma-style syntax is only for backward compatibility with pre-1992 SQL.  They perform exactly the same, but the 1992 syntax can do outer joins and it's easier to read.

PS: PHP supports multi-line strings, so there's no need to concatenate strings together as you're doing.  That's a Java habit.

Comment: better yet, use a HEREDOC for multi-line strings. far easier to deal with than having to embed newlines everywhere.

Comment: Heredocs are fine, but fwiw the multi-line strings also implicitly contain newlines.  No need to use "\n".

Comment: I just want the name so it goes like this `SELECT client.name
    FROM account JOIN client USING (client_id) 
    WHERE account.id = 19` Thanks for the idea and help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple inner join will do the task

```
 $query = "select 
                  account.id,client.client_id 
           from 
                  account 
           join 
                  client 
            on 
                  account.client_id = client.client_id 
           where 
                  account.id = 19";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work using an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM Client C
   INNER JOIN Account A ON C.Client_Id = A.Client_Id
WHERE A.Id = 19
```

You're query is producing a Cartesian Product since you aren't joining the tables on any field.

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: It does work but I don't understand this thing `c.name`, `Client C`, `Account A` etc etc. What does this `c` and `C` means? It's like you declare a new temporary variable in the query? Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @sg552 -- np, glad we could help.  In regards to the "a" and the "c", those are just aliases on the tables -- shorthand instead of having to type Client.Name or Client.Client_Id you can just type c.name or c.Client_Id.  Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't join Account and Client.
And moreover you want only the client name and the query has to be:

```
Select distinct client.client_name from account, client where client.client_id=account.account_id and account_id=19
```

Comment: for a given account_id there's only one client_id, hence only one client_name

Comment: hmm all I see is the mandatory filter `account.id = 19`. With this, you will get one and only one client_id

Comment: It works after a few fixed here and there :) `SELECT DISTINCT client.name
FROM account, client
WHERE client.client_id = account.client_id
AND id =19
LIMIT 0 , 30` Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = " SELECT account.id, client.client_id
           FROM `account`
     INNER JOIN `client` ON `client`.client_id = `account`.`client_id`
          WHERE account.id = 19";
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment that *explains* your SELECT statement.

Comment: @Trinimon, that's what the internet is for. There is plenty of documentation around. Sometimes you just want the answer, it's just English otherwise. If you don't know what join means, and explanation will not help him

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide information about the structure of your client table, this is just a guess:

```
SELECT account.id, client.client_id
FROM account, client
WHERE account.id = 19
  AND account.client_id = client.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
$sql = "SELECT account.id, client.client_id
        FROM account, client
        WHERE account.client_id=client.id AND account.id = 19 "
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you
Select c.name, c.client_id, a.id from account a left join on client c on a.client_id = c.client_id
Where a.id = 19